# Adjektivendungen mit Genitiv und Indefinitpronomen für eine unbestimmte Anzahl

Tags: adjective-ending

> Wessen grün_ Mantel ist das?
> Er ist Besitzer vieler teur_ Autos (Genitiv).

I‘m trying to solve some exercises on Adjektivendungen and I‘m facing difficulty understanding these two parts. The answers of the book are:

> grün**er** und teur**er**

Whereas I thought the answers should be -*en* und -*en*.

Could you please explain to me why the endings are -*er*? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Wessen?* is a question word which is followed be the nominative case, and expects an answer in the genitive case.

You need the [strong declension without articles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gr%C3%BCn#Declension).

> Ein grüner Mantel. -> Wessen grüner Mantel? -> [Der grüne Mantel]<sub>1</sub> [der Frau]<sub>2</sub>.

<sub>1</sub>*Nominative, definite article*
<sub>2</sub>*Genitive*

Or in the plural case

> Wessen grüne Mäntel? -> Die grünen Mäntel der Frau.

2. 

*Viel* ist actually a special case, which is quite complicated and even confused me as a native speaker.

You can treat it as an indefinite amount ([Numerale indefinitum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun)), which then requires the
[mixed declension plural genitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teuer) form.

> Er ist Besitzer vieler teuren Autos

Or you can treat it as a fellow adjective, so both adjective will be in the strong plural genitive case

> Er ist Besitzer vieler teurer Autos

similar to

> Er ist Besitzer schneller teurer Autos